# gráfico no visual basic

Tags: visual-basic-6

Como faço para que quando aperto o botão, o VB desenhe o gráfico usando o componente `chart`?

Está dando problema na `private sub`, porque aparecem duas: a do `button` e a do `chart`.

Comment: Olá Priscila! Bem-vinda ao SOpt. Recomendo que faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) do site para entender como conseguir melhores respostas para suas dúvidas. Creio que você precisa fornecer mais informações para te ajudarmos. Você poderia começar mostrando o código?